# How to get LittleSnitch to block incoming and outgoing connections?

Tags: firewall

I use littlesnitch 5 and am happy with it overall.

However, since I had to re-install it after a disk crash, my rules to block incoming and outgoing connections have stopped working.

To stop incoming and outgoing connections, I created a little snitch profile called "STOP CONNECTIONS".

In that profile, I created four rules:

```
1. incoming-deny all from any process 
2. incoming-deny from any server
3. outgoing- deny any process
4. outgoing- deny any server
```

The problem is that all the other rules are active in all profiles so these rules, even when I enable this "STOP CONNECTIONS" profile do not work. Connections not stopped.

So, my question is how to configure little snitch so I have a profile I can switch to that blocks all connections.

I had this working before the disk crash so I'm baffled why I can't get it working again.

Thanks very much for your kind replies and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

create a standard profile, move existing rules to this profile - then if you want to block choose your "stop connections" profile else use the new standard profile.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make the rules higher in precedence. Then they worked. Thanks to all.